# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returning error 1 code

Tags: c++, sqlite

I wanted to clean up my sql insert function and use prepared statements instead of a hacked string within sqlite3_exec. I keep getting issues trying to use it. Here is the code:

```
void Database::insert(char* tableName,int time1,int x,int y,int z)
{

int i;
i = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "insert into ?1 values(?2, ?3, ?4, ?5);", -1, &stmt, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, tableName, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

std::cout <<i<< std::endl;
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, time1);

std::cout <<"made it int1"<< std::endl;
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, x);

std::cout <<"made it int2"<< std::endl;
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, y);

std::cout <<"made it int3"<< std::endl;
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 5, z);



 rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
 if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
     std::cout << "SQL error: "<< errMsg << std::endl;
 } else {
   std::cout << "insert successfully" << std::endl;
 }
 std::cout << "boom2"<< std::endl;
 sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
 }
```

database.h file:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H


#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Database
{


public:

  Database(char* name);
  ~Database();
  int openConnection(char* name);
  void insert(char* table, int vTime, int x, int y, int z);
  void closeConnection();
  void createTable(char* dbName);
  void getData(char* table, int time1);

private:
  sqlite3* db;
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  char *errMsg;
  int rc;
  char* dbName;
  std::string sqlStatement;
  const char* sql;
};


static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

When I run this code, I get a seg fault 11 when trying to insert something into the provided table. I get errors related to prepare returning 1 and rc being code 21 (SQL_MISUSE). My question is what is wrong with my prepared statement?

Comment: To get an error message, call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You get the SQL_MISUSE error because you tried to use a prepared statement that did not exist.

The prepare failed because you tried to use a parameter for a table name. Parameters work only for literal values in expressions, not for table/column names.